# How to do this C++ comma + ternary operator in C#?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I'm still in the process of learning C# recently, and got stuck on the documentation when I tried to convert this C++ comma operator with ternary operator into C# code:

This is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  bool test1 = false;
  bool test2 = true;

  cout << 
    ((test1) ? 
      "pass me" : 
      (test1 = true, (test2) ?        //Comma inside test condition
        ((test1) ? 
          (test1 = false, "get me") : //Comma inside return condition
          "pass me") : 
        "pass me")) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

But when I try to do it in C#

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program {
  static void Main() {
    bool test1 = false;
    bool test2 = true;

    Console.WriteLine( ((test1) ? 
                         "pass me" : 
                         ((test1 = true, test2) ? 
                           "get me" : 
                           "pass me")));
  }
}
```

C# doesn't seem to support it, so I'm wondering how to build the code for it.

Thank you.

Comment: It makes me happy that that's not legal C#.  That code is way harder to read than it ought to be.  The ternary operator is best used with side effect free expressions.  You've labeled this question with the "functional-programming" tag, but this expression is not at all in a functional style.

Comment: Wow, what truly atrocious code.

Answer (score 4):

You're better off refactoring that whole expression into a separate function.

Like this:

```
private static bool EvaluateTest(ref bool test1, ref bool test)
{
  if (test1) {
    return "pass me";
  } else {
    test1 = true;
    if (test2) {
      if (test1) {
        test1 = false;
        return "get me";
      } else {
        return "pass me";
      }
    } else {
      return "pass me";
    }
  }
}
```

I think that's correct, but I haven't tested it. The expression is hard to follow so I might have missed something somewhere (and I haven't written C# code for a while), but this at least gives the idea of what I'm talking about.

The logic here doesn't even make sense because, if I'm reading the original expression correctly, `test1` will always be true in the last `if (test1)` test... something that becomes obvious if you write it clearly like this.

And if you **must** write an expression using embedded ternary operators like that, **please** at least use proper indentation, i.e. indent it as you would with nested if-else blocks.

Comment: Thank you, I had the code like what you're showing, but I would like to trimmed it down at the cost of readability since I enjoy writing less, but thanks again for convincing me to go back to if-else statement.

Comment: But I'll keep the question open to see if there's away to recreate the comma functionality from C++ in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I would never code like this, but in C# the comma operator does not work as shown in your code. This however will work (bad coding if you are doing this though).

```
Console.WriteLine( (test1) ? "pass me" 
                       : ((test1 = true)== test2) ? "get me" 
                                                  : "pass me");
```

Based on what I see you doing you do not need to set test1 to true as, rather check the state of test2. The assumption is that if test1 is false, test2 is your next condition to check.

```
 Console.WriteLine( (test1) ? "pass me" 
                       : (test2) ? "get me" 
                                 : "pass me");
```

Comment: @AD.Net He did **not** write `test1 == true`.  What he did write is not equivalent to `test1`.

Comment: `"Note this also translates to [...]"` no it doesn't.  Not at all.

Comment: @Servy it does, he is explicitly setting test1 to true and comparing to test2.

Comment: @TYY Yes, it's *mutating the variable*.  Changing it to code that doesn't mutate the variable is then not equivalent code.

Comment: @Servy that is true. I will change the "this translates to"